# How to Click the Tab

Tags: java, html, selenium

I want to click the "Get" tab illustrated in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8R8VO.png). But unable to click. Can someone please help me?

HTML is:

```html
 <div id="schemeSlabTab" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top">
    <a href="#Init_Buy_Grid">Buy</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active">
    <a href="#Init_Get_Grid" style="background-color: transparent;">Get</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: do you have a demo to view, i am a little unclear on what you are asking. Do you mean click Programmatically?

Comment: Yes, i want to click programmatically only(Automation).  I use Selenium and Java for Scripting. I used    "WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'#Init_Get_Grid')]")).findElement(By.linkText("Get"));      " for getting the xpath and clicked the element. But control is not clicking the Tab. Is there any other way to click the Tab.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Have you tried the below option? If yes, what issue/error did you got?

    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Get"));

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'#Init_Get_Grid')]")).findElement(By.linkText("Get")); 
element.click();
```

Comment: @JamesRisner, he has missed the second like thats why its not working. How answer should be given in comments!